# Is it okay to create PHP variables this way?

Tags: php

Consider:

```
 $snode->field_length = array();
 $snode->field_length['und'] = array();
 $snode->field_length['und'][0] = array();
 $snode->field_length['und'][0]['value'] = 5;
```

Versus just writing:

```
 $snode->field_length['und'][0]['value'] = 5;
```

In the second case, you are assigning to fields that don't exist. However, PHP doesn't complain. Does that mean it's okay to code like this?

Comment: Yes, it is OK... You're creating the indexes.

Comment: The docs say so: _If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array._ http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: ^^ But they go on to say _This practice is however discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and [] may actually stand for string access operator._

Comment: You should add the first line of your first block to the second block: Define / reset it and then use it directly at the depth required. In my opinion :-)

Comment: If you're confident it won't cause the problem described in your code base, and your collaborators agree, then there's no issue.

Comment: When populating new structures `= ["und" => [ 0 => ["value" => 5] ] ];` is sometimes easier to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is ok, but maybe is not the clearest way to write it.

PHP has dynamic typing, so it is not necessary to specify the type of a variable before using it, because the interpreter is responsible for inferring what type you're trying to assign at runtime.

I would consider using array intializers:

```
$snode->field_length = array(
    'und' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 5
        )
    )
);
```

Or, even better, in PHP >= 5.4:

```
$snode->field_length = [
    'und' => [
        [
            'value' => 5
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do as @mchurichi answers says but if there's the case, when you don't know the previous value, use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
if(!is_array($snode->field_length)){
    $snode->field_length = array();
}

$snode->field_length = array_merge_recursive($snode->field_length, array(
    'und' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 5
        )
    )
));
```